# Which language has what particular advantage

Tags: language-comparison, beneficial-effects

My English ability reached a certain level so that I appreciate it only starting from this year. It helped me access to tons of knowledge and information placed online. Tons of lecture notes, tons of good blogs, tons of wonderful in-depth videos, including this site.. this list does not stop.

This does not seem to be the case for my native language. Somehow people were not that engaged in the internet world. That being said, it has its own beauty, usefulness, and advantage. In fact, I believe this applies to all languages.

> Question: Are there languages that can unlock opportunities in an "unexpected" way?

I should clarify what I mean by "unexpected" here with some examples:

- Learning a language X unlocks the opportunities for you to communicate with people who speak language X better -- this is not unexpected.
- Learning a language X enables you to understand its related culture and history more -- this is not unexpected.
- Learning English enabled me to get access to lots of information and in-depth knowledge in almost any area, simply because lots of people in the world speak and use English. Not deniably, it is sort of a norm. (I don't want to argue that.)
- Learning French, German, and Latin enables one to get access to lots of scientific and philosophical old literature and discussions. The benefit, I imagine, will be "unexpected", since it feels different when I read Gauss or Euler's word directly.

Besides these.. I feel like there are still lots of good stuff out there, which I would never know until I grok a particular language. That's exactly why I asked this question, sincerely!

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning.SE! This post looks like an opinion poll or survey, not an answerable question. This type of posts is not particularly appreciated on both this site and the entire Stack Exchange network. Do you have any specific question in mind or any specific problem you're trying to solve? If so, please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed my phrase and now it looks less like an opinion poll.

Comment: Advantage in doing what? What are your interests? As you found, English is "the original" language of the Internet and most widely used for most activities. But if you are interested in ancient Chinese or Japanese history, Yoga, or current trends in Tango, then Chinese, Japanese, Hindi or Spanish (accordingly) might give yo more "advantage".

Comment: Similarly, learning your religion's holy language or language of scripture can give you deeper insight into its teachings and practices, and can even open doorways to eventual ordination.